# execute copy command from aws glue to connect to redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm trying to execute copy command in redshift via glue

redshiftsql = 'copy table from s3://bucket/test credentials 'aws-iam-role fromat json as 'auto';"

I'm connecting using below syntax

from_jdbc_conf(frame, catalog_connection, connection_options={}, redshift_tmp_dir = "", transformation_ctx="")

what is the value I need to pass for frame ? Any thoughts ? I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly you can pass "extracopyoptions":"" in the connection_options object for redshift, anything from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html

See this archived question from AWS premium support.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job/

By the way this is very poorly documented in my opinion.